# What is the difference between setBackgroundResource and setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: android, view, background, android-drawable

Could anyone tell me what is the difference between `setBackgroundResource(resourceid)` and `setBackgroundDrawable(getResource().getDrawable(drawableid))` in android?

Comment: The two lines you provided - no difference.  However note that `setBackgroundDrawable` doesn't have to get a drawable from resources - it can be an image downloaded from the internet or a bitmap created on the fly.

Comment: but when i disabled a button and then enabling, the greyed color to the button not removing(here at first i used setBackgroundResource for setting background drawable again but it is not showing any difference, and then i used setBackgroundDrawable then the button background changed to actual drawable). Why both methods showing different behaviour if they've no difference.

Comment: Could you post some code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Removing of grayed colour on enabling/disabling may not work if you set a simple background resource.  You need to set up state selector background if you want different colours for different states (e.g. gray for disabled, yellow for enabled, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

You can have a look at the [Android source code for the View class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) yourself and find out that there is very little difference!

```
public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
    if (resid != 0 && resid == mBackgroundResource) {
        return;
    }

    Drawable d= null;
    if (resid != 0) {
        d = mResources.getDrawable(resid);
    }
    setBackground(d);

    mBackgroundResource = resid;
}
```

And `setBackground()` just calls through to `setBackgroundDrawable()`...

```
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    //noinspection deprecation
    setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}
```

Comment: Straight from the droid's mouth.